# How to forward the parameters from one page to another jsp page?

Tags: jsp

Am New to jsp I had to forward the name from one file to another. After a lot of dig I found the below code to be worked but it wasn't work. I have three jsp files like oneMain.jsp, twoMain.jsp and threeMain.jsp. I forward the name threeMain from oneMain.jsp to twoMain.jsp. So that I can display the content of the threeMain.jsp page

oneMain.jsp code is

```
<jsp:forward page="twoMain.jsp">
<jsp:param name="visualName" value="threeMain.jsp"/>
</jsp:forward>
```

twoMain.jsp code is

```
<jsp:forward page="<%= request.getParameter("visualName")%>"/>
```

Finally I want threeMain.jsp content to be displayed.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the code below on how you can pass parameters between jsp pages. You can use the `<jsp:forward ... >` to forward a request using this code:

```
<jsp:forward page="newjsp1.jsp">
  <jsp:param name="par1" value="111" ></jsp:param>
</jsp:forward>
```

This will forward the response to `newjsp1.jsp` with a parameter `par1` and its value is `111`.

Now in newjsp1.jsp you can read this parameter using:

```
<jsp:scriptlet>
  out.append(request.getParameter("par1"));
</jsp:scriptlet>
```

You can also share attributes between pages using the `session` implicit Object... Possibilities are limitless...

Maybe you would like to check these pages out:

1. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm
2. http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/

Comment: In your example I want to pass "threeMain.jsp" instead of "111". So When I read it in another page I can directly forward to threeMain.jsp like `<jsp:forward page="<%= request.getParameter("visualName")%>"/>` Is this possible?.

Comment: not exactly. Check this `<%response.sendRedirect(request.getParameter("par1"));%>`

Comment: but be aware that the `redirect` is different from the `forward` action

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I used <%response.sendRedirect(request.getParameter("par1"));%> it is working properly. But In my page session variables are there, after I redirect to another page I can't get the value there

Comment: yes, thats right, because its a clean request. You can store values in session object though. `session.setAttribute("par1","value1");` and get them in the other jsp like this `String s = session.getAttribute("par1").toString();`