# How to get attribute from another page

Tags: java, jsp

Lets say I have page1.jsp and I doing:

```
request.setAttribute("message", "Here is my error message");
response.sendRedirect("page2.jsp");
```

In my page2.jsp I try to get that message by using this code:

```
<%= (String)request.getAttribute("message") %>
```

But the result is null. I could do this `response.sendRedirect("page2.jsp?message=error message");` and get the message with `request.getParameter` but I don't like this approach. Any other idea?

Comment: A redirect causes a **new** request/response cycle. Request attributes set in the first request don't exist in the second. You'll need session (or application) attributes to persist anything between requests.

Comment: One way would be to store the attribute in session, make the redirect and in the other page use the attribute, then remove it from session.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yeah I suspected that this is the cause of null result but how I can request the other page without causing new request?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yeah that also one alternative way but I think there should be a better way.

Comment: You could use a forward too...

Comment: It depends what you mean by _request_. A redirect is a specific situation where you send a response with a 301 (302?) response code with a `Location` header specifying where to send the new request. Is that what you want or do you just want to render the other JSP in the same response as the original?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just want to be able to pass message (or even array, objects) and then call the other page and get this message (or array, object) from that page.

Comment: Then session attributes are appropriate.

Comment: If it is through a redirect, use session attributes. If it is through forward, use request attributes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I just wanted to do this in request scope not in session. setting and unsetting session is not the best way.

Comment: @Almis who told you that's the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can forward the request instead of redirecting it. Forwarding is transparent to the user, whereas a redirect actually sends a 302 response code and creates a new request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043388/how-to-forward-the-parameters-from-one-page-to-another-jsp-page